# Sublime Text 3 snippet not working in plain text file with no extension

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have the following snippet that I would like to work in a plain text file, specifically **before** the file has been saved with an extension or having set a syntax.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/* yay this is your generic test snippet */
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>generic</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.plain</scope>
    <description>Generic any scope snippet</description>
</snippet>
```

However it doesn't work when I type `generic` in a new file. I have already made this change to sublime user settings:

```
    "auto_complete_selector": "source, text, source - comment"
```

**Follow-up note**
Omitting the `<scope>` from the snippet definition should make it available in all scopes, it worked for me with the above snippet in `sql` and `markdown` scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix by doing the following, but I'll accept any other better answer.

In syntax-specific (plain text) user settings I made added the `""` to the extensions field:

```
"extensions":
[
    "txt", ""
],
```

Now the snippet works in newly created unsaved files, or files without an extension.